# Animate dynamically-defined content of a WPF control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I need to create a `UserControl` with variable appearance but common behavior. I.e. appearance can be different: a `Square`, a `Polygon`, or an `Ellipse`. But the control needs to be able to animate (fade in and out) the said `Square`/`Polygon`/`Ellipse`.

I can create three different controls and define a `Storyboard` in each, and point the Storyboard to whatever Shape I have inside my control. But I want to define the Storyboard only once to follow the DRY principle. So I created a control without content like this and want to point the storyboards to whatever content it will have:

```
<UserControl x:Class="wpf_test.StarControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_test"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="FadeInStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="?????"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0:0:2"
                             From="0"
                             To="1"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="FadeOutStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="?????"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0:0:2"
                             From="1"
                             To="0"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    

</UserControl>
```

I can then put whatever Shape I need inside that control, e.g. using a `Syle` with `Template` setter, but my problem I don't know how to point my `Storyboard`s to that future Shape, i.e. what to put into the `Storyboard.TargetName="?????"` instead of the question marks.

Comment: Did you try a name on the usercontrol?

Comment: Animate the Opacity of the UserControl itself.

Comment: Thanks, Andy, and EldHasp. Your answers helped. I didn't know it's that simple. Feel free to post your comments as answers if you want an upvote from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Andy's and @EldHasp's comments, the solution was to add a name on the UserControl and animate the Opacity of the UserControl itself.

```
<UserControl x:Class="wpf_test.StarControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_test"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="ThisStarControl">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="FadeInStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ThisStarControl"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0:0:2"
                             From="0"
                             To="1"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="FadeOutStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ThisStarControl"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0:0:2"
                             From="1"
                             To="0"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    
</UserControl>
```